# SharedPreferences produces force close in android program

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm building an android project that contains `SharedPreferences`.

My  `SharedPreferences` works fine and I tested it in mutiple activity. but in a class that I defined for global variables, defining that `SharedPreferences` will cause force close (eclipse didn't show any error in codes).

```
public class Globals extends Application {

    final SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: SharedPreferences can be obtained only from Context. So it needs to be `context.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` Your clas s know nothing about Context - this is problem. You need to pass Context variable as parameter in method or through constructor.

Comment: i chaged it :        final SharedPreferences s = this.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);        but still producs force close.

Comment: You cannot use this because you're not in Activity (Activities extends from Context for this reason you can use this or not). You need explictly pass Context as parameter or method or constructor. There is not other way how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `Context` and use

`SharedPreferences prefs = Context.getSharedPreferences(
      "Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor and pass a Context variable as a parameter. Any activity that want to use this preference then you have to pass the activity. Here's the code given below:

```
public class Globals  extends Application {

    private Context context;

    public Globals (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    SharedPreferences myPref = context.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `getSharedPreferences()` in the actual class. Everything you do must be in the Application's `onCreate` method. If you try to run this in the class, it will fail since it has not been initialized yet. Think of it almost as an activity, since both the activity and the application have a lifecycle.

Try the following:

```
public class Globals extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        final SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```